# Coefficients in binomial expansions of $(x+y)^n$

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Is it true that if we expand $(x+y)^n$ where $n$ is a prime number, then all the coefficients are divisible (except the first and last term) by $n$?

Note. There are many examples of when $n$ isn't prime, and the coefficients are not divisible by $n$.

Comment: Write out the definition of the general term pCr where p is the prime, and notice that it is an integer, but the p in the numerator has not cancelled out

Comment: this is known as [Freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) and was already asked quite often, just check out the link or use the search - you'll find what you're looking for for sure, like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238531/proving-the-freshmans-dream)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i} x^iy^{n-i}$$

So all you need to prove is that ${p\choose i}$ is divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime.