# Prove that $a^m+b^m=(a+b)^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field such that $char F=p\neq 0$, let $n>0$ and $m=p^n$ prove that $a^m+b^m=(a+b)^m$ for all $a,b\in F$

*Attempt:*

Since $a,b\in F$ then $a^m=(1\cdot a)^m=1^ma^m=0\cdot a^m=0$

and $b^m=(1\cdot b)^m=1^mb^m=0\cdot b^m=0\implies a^m+b^m=\color{red}0$

$(a+b)^m=[1\cdot (a+b)]^m=(1)^m(a+b)^m=0\cdot (a+b)^m=\color{red}0$

[Relatet, but not the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238531/proving-the-freshmans-dream)

Comment: $1^m = 1$, not $0$.  I think the best way to prove this is by induction on $n$, the exponent in $m= p^n$. The base case, $n=1$, should be known to you as the freshman's dream. The induction step shouldn't be too hard

Comment: $1^m\neq 0$ in a ring with characteristic $p$: $m\cdot 1=0$. This is just a trivial repeated application of [the last question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274494/prove-that-apbp-abp)

Comment: Binomial theorem works for commutative rings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction on $n$. Suppose $a^m' + b^m' =(a+b)^m'$ then taking $p$th power and using binomial theorem on LHS we deduce the same holds for $pm$. For $m=p$ this is obvious since $p| pCi$ for all $0<i<p$